# Process CSV files

Tags: ios, swift, csv

I'm new to IOS development and not sure what is the best approach to use. I have csv files totals of 250MB. I need to process some files base on user selection on UI.For that matter, should I just load all csv files into my project or should I just set up REST server and make a request as needed?

Answer (score 1):

Processing and fetching records from CSV files are not optimised.

If your app works offline - like Dictionaries - it's better to use sqlite or realm, otherwise you can setup a REST server

Comment: Yes my app works offline. There are all together maybe about 1000 csv files and they follow special naming scheme. That means I can just generate a filename that I need to load base on user selection. And these files contains no more than 10 records and I don't need complex query since I'm displaying all those records. Do you still recommend sqlite or realm?

Comment: I still recommend sqlite. about 1000 tables there will be. working with sql SELECT command is far more easy yo fetch data